# How to strip more than symbols?

Tags: executable, functions, symbols

I've noticed that, even after stripping symbols from my executable, class names and their methods are still included at the end of the executable file.

For instance:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Clingons
{
public:
    void clingForever()
    {
        cout << "Qapla" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Clingons cling;

    cling.clingForever();

    return 0;
}
```

Then compile and link with:

```
g++ cling.cpp -o cling
```

Now, when I look at the bottom of the resulting "cling" file with a hex editor, I can see the "Clingons" class name along with it's methods. I can also see this information while debugging..

even after I strip them:

```
strip -x cling
```

I can still see the same information.

So why wasn't this information stripped away when I used the command above? Is there a way to strip (or mangle) this information other than by hand?

The used version of GCC is `i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1`

This is just an example case. My real project involves the Qt framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that you are using RTTI.
Try compiling your code with option `-fno-rtti`.

Update: It is really RTTI.

I don't know how exactly it works, but I succeeded to remove those strings as follows:

```
$ g++ -Xlinker -unexported_symbol -Xlinker "*" -o executable file.cpp
$ strip executable
```

(This was found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931626/how-to-really-strip-a-binary-in-macos )

Comment: Keep in mind that there are edge cases where RTTI may indeed be *required* at runtime, though.

Comment: I know about this one (I commented on the accepted answer) but it doesn't seem to remove everything from my current Qt project.

Comment: @Access Denied: RTTI is disabled by default on Qt libraries so I don't think disabling it would cause an issue. I tried disabling it via -fno-rtti and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I realize that this solution does work. It does keep references to classes and functions in external libraries but nothing from my own code.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling your program as a static assembly, and strip it using the compiler.  You won't find any 'cling' references in the resultant executable.

```
$ g++ -static -s cling.cpp -o cling

$ ls -l cling*
-rwxr-x--- 1 lornix lornix 1,313,792 Jun 22 19:19 cling*
-rw-r----- 1 lornix lornix       222 Jun 22 19:16 cling.cpp

$ strings -a cling | grep -ic cling
0
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it wouldn't build: can't locate file for: -lcrt0.o ... Also, my real project is using the Qt framework so I can't build static unless I purchase a commercial license.

Answer (score 1):

The toolbox [ELFKicker](http://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/elfkickers.html) has an utility called `sstrip` that strip an ELF executable down to the bones.

But, it seems that you are using Mach-O executable format. So, I would recommend to look at the [source code of `sstrip`](https://github.com/BR903/ELFkickers/blob/master/sstrip/sstrip.c) and build your own stripper.

You can also take a look at the [source code of the `strip` command for Mach-O](https://github.com/gdbinit/otool-ng/blob/master/cctools/misc/strip.c) and get inspiration. And, also, this [Python script `strip_save_dsym`](https://web.archive.org/web/20150528181706/http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/build/mac/strip_save_dsym) might also give some hints.

Finally, here are a few comparisons between ELF and Mach-O formats:

- [Dynamic Linking: ELF vs. Mach-O](http://timetobleed.com/dynamic-linking-elf-vs-mach-o/)
- [Dynamic symbol table duel: ELF vs Mach-O, round 2](http://timetobleed.com/dynamic-symbol-table-duel-elf-vs-mach-o-round-2/)
- [Crafting a Tiny Mach-O Executable](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161741/http://osxbook.com/blog/2009/03/15/crafting-a-tiny-mach-o-executable/)

Comment: Although your answer doesn't provide an instant solution, it's bold and I like it a lot. Studying sstrip looks like fun and maybe I'll end up creating my own special tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks, but I also totally agree with your choice of marking WS answer as the answer ! Mine is, at most, some complementary information about the topic.